# dynamically creating object [java]

Tags: java

This might be a simple question to answer but I am new to programming. My question is how do I create an instance of a class dynamically. For example I have a circle class which has methods of calculate area and half area and so on and the classes constructor initialises all the class fields like the radius and other fields. What I want to be able to do is create an instance of the class whenever a user wants to create a new circle. To create a circle class this is what I currently have

```
circle c1 = new circle(radius);
```

but this object is statically created when I write the code, so how can I create a new instance of a class when a user wants to create a new object.

Thank you for any help in advance.
Please be nice new to programming.

Comment: initialize `c1` when the user wants it to be created?

Comment: it is a simple case of if-else statement .
if user wants an object then create it and return it to c1.
else do whatever the code flow wants.

Comment: if you want to create your object when user requested, just put your line in block which is handling interaction with user. Ie in button listener

Answer (score 1):

Have a look how simple it could be

```
 Circle c1 ;
 //{
    // your users wish and store it in some boolean var .
 //}

 if (userWantsObjectCreation) {
       c1 = new Circle();
 }
 else {
    // your holy logic here instead if object creation .
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand the code that you have given but I wanted to know how I create a new instance of a class when a user wants a new instance of a circle class, In the code above will it create a new instance of the circle or will it overide the existing circle object that has been created

Comment: Basically  we  don't override objects , you have the circle definition(Circle class).Now whenever you require just create an object , as you have mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can take input from user asking for "create circle? enter Y or N" and then use if else condition

```
if("Y".equals(input))
{
c1 = new Circle();
}

else{
//something else
}
```

Comment: Don't, ever, compare Strings with `==`.

Comment: just small suggestion, change it to "Y".equals(input) so you will make it null  safe, otherwise you are risking NPE

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to store all the created circles in a "list" structure.

For example:

```
List<Circle> list = new ArrayList<Circle>();

Circle c1 = new Circle(radius);
list.add(c1);

...

void onUserClickedCreateCircle() {
    Circle c = new Circle(15);
    list.add(c);
}

void renderAllCirclesOnScreen() {
    //Take each circle from the list into variable c
    for (Circle c : list) {
        drawCircle(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax as the following:

```
ObjectName obj=Class.forName("object name full name").newInstance();
```

For example, you have class named Car, which is resided in com.toyota package.
Then you can instantiate Car object using the following statement:

```
Car car=(Car)Class.forName("com.toyota.Car").newInstance();
```

Comment: This should also be avoided unless you have a legitimate need for it. Reflection isn't meant to be used as a do-all tool, when there are perfectly valid methods to accomplish the same thing with regular programming.